# Python regex get multiple lines after specific word

Tags: python, regex, loops, string-matching

The string is stored in a variable text.
When I do print(text) I get the output:

```
SHIP TO
Flensburg House, MMDA Colony,
Arumbakkam,Chennai, Tamil Nadu,
```

I need to get the text:

```
Flensburg House, MMDA Colony,
Arumbakkam,Chennai, Tamil Nadu,
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
shipto=[]
shipto_re=re.compile(r"SHIP TO((?:.*\n){1,3})")
for line in text.split():
      if shipto_re.match(line):
        shipto.append(line)
```

However, this isn't giving me a match,I know the regex works , so the problem definitely lies in how to iterate through the text variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a regex that matches across lines, but you split the string with whitespace and test each split "token" against the regex.

You need to use

```py
import re
text = r'''SHIP TO
Flensburg House, MMDA Colony,
Arumbakkam,Chennai, Tamil Nadu,
'''
shipto_re=re.compile(r"SHIP TO((?:.*\n){1,3})")
shipto = [x.strip() for x in shipto_re.findall(text)]
print(shipto)
# => ['Flensburg House, MMDA Colony,\nArumbakkam,Chennai, Tamil Nadu,']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/siwgah).

Here, `Pattern.findall` is used to extract Group 1 value from the matches, and each match is stripped off any leading and trailing whitespace with `str.strip()`.

**More considerations**

If you plan to match a line even if it is at the end of a string, you need to replace the regex with

```py
shipto_re=re.compile(r"SHIP TO(.*(?:\n.*){0,2})")
```

The `SHIP TO(.*(?:\n.*){0,2})` matches `SHIP TO` and then captures into Group 1 any text till end of the current line, then zero, one or two sequences of a newline (LF) char and then the rest of that line (with `(.*(?:\n.*){0,2})`).

Comment: The output seems incorrect. it leaves out "Arumbakkam,Chennai, Tamil Nadu,".

Comment: @JacobJarick It is fine with the way I defined the string variable. OP just has a trailing newline that I did not add. See the edit.

Comment: ahh excellent catch, I revisted my answer and was wondering why it wasnt working.

Answer (score 0):

You regex is correct.

I believe your issue is the use of text.split() which by default splits on any whitespace meaning it trys to match per word.

Instead simply use findall.

```
import re

text="""SHIP TO
Flensburg House, MMDA Colony,
Arumbakkam,Chennai, Tamil Nadu,
"""
shipto=[]
shipto_re=re.compile(r"SHIP TO((?:.*\n){1,3})")
shipto += shipto_re.findall(text)

print (shipto)
```

fiddle: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/CgUoXrxqKxK

Answer (score 0):

Here you go... sample code ->

```
import re
regex = r"SHIP TO(.*)"
test_str = ("SHIP TO\n"
    "Flensburg House, MMDA Colony,\n"
    "Arumbakkam,Chennai, Tamil Nadu,")
matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.DOTALL)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        lines = match.group(groupNum).strip().split("\n")
        print(lines)
```

The thing is you have to use `re.DOTALL` flag